# How to export A1 B1 one below other

Tags: excel, text, formatting

i need help to export excel file into text file. My excel file have 2 columns, A and B. Need to export this to be ordered like:

```
A1 
B1
A2
B2
A3
B3
An
Bn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in *Sheet1* like:

[image]

In *Sheet2* cell **A1** enter:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/2,0)-1,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,2))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Then SaveAs text.

You could also do this with a VBA macro.

Comment: The formula you typed contains an error. Black(ed) on $A$1,ROUNDUP.

Answer (score 1):

Or use this NON Volatile formula, put this in A1 of another sheet and copy/drag down:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$B,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/2)+1,MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,2)+1)
```

Then save that sheet as a text file.

Sheet1:

[image]

Sheet2:

[image]

Comment: The formula you typed contains an error. Black(ed) on $B,INT.

Comment: Do you use `;` instead of `,` to delineate between criteria?  Try changing all `,` to `;`.

Comment: @krazors please do not edit the post to change to `;` this site is supposed to be in American English standard and "," is used to delineate in American English Excel.